# No audio in Dell Vostro 1310 bios a11

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have a problem of sound hearing in my laptop dell vostro 1310. I installed Windows 7 64 bit but it does not give out sound but all audio setting and driver show up everything is ok but nothing hearing in both output speakers and internal I tryed to update but nothing

Comment: I wouldn't expect the BIOS to make much difference, did you install the audio drivers for it though?

Comment: yes i install it and i update by using updating driver software but still not working

Answer (score 0):

When you have driver problems the best is to go to the official website and check for you possibilities.

For Dell it is really easy to troubleshoot driver problems.

Go to this site: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/vostro-1310/diagnose

Press the "Full Test" button and follow the instructions.